# UITextView Detection Types - Need examples

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uitextview

In `UITextView` there are detection attributes I can set. `Links` I can obviously check and it is working fine. but I was unable to learn what kind of `Addresses` and `Events` `UITextView` can detect.

Can someone please give examples of what types/formats of events and addresses it can detect.

There's nothing in documentation either.